# minikube embedded docker fails to connect to private insecure registry over the network

Tags: minikube, docker-registry

My system:

```
georgek@kalamata:~/dev/docker/flights$ uname -a
Linux kalamata 5.15.0-33-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 18 13:34:26 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

georgek@kalamata:~/dev/docker/flights$ minikube version
minikube version: v1.25.2
commit: 362d5fdc0a3dbee389b3d3f1034e8023e72bd3a7

georgek@kalamata:~/dev/docker/flights$ kubectl version --short
Flag --short has been deprecated, and will be removed in the future. The --short output will become the default.
Client Version: v1.24.0
Kustomize Version: v4.5.4
Server Version: v1.23.3
```

I have a toy private registry created inside an AWS VM.

I start minikube with

```
minikube start --insecure-registry <IP>:5000
```

I try to do a deployment with

```
kubectl create deployment flights-node --image=<IP>:5000/flights
```

... and it fails with

```
Failed to pull image "<IP>:5000/flights": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "http://<IP>:5000/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I did do a `minikube ssh` and tried to run a `docker pull <IP>:5000/flights` with no success so I know what the problem is (the same `docker pull` command from my own docker install outside minikube works fine!).

I am new to kubernetes so any suggestions/ideas will help me immensely!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at similar posts made on private registries and minikube and all had a simple underlying premise, reboot :).

I did reboot my system and voila I am now able to fetch the image from my private registry.

If anyone knows the underlying reason as to why a reboot is needed please share.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after some time, but if someone encounters something like this, check your firewall. In my case, I lost an hour just to find UFW rule has to be corrected..